# How to stop .animate() when it reaches the last picture?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

When i click the next button to slide in next, it slides and stops with the last picture in left side but this is my problem here.

1st: I want to stop the last picture in the right side of the gallery, so it fills the gallery with last pictures because in my code it slides all last pictures and hides all.

2nd: when i continue clicking the button to the end, it continue sliding for it is not to continue.

3rd: I want to slide the images in the right width, how  can i code this ?

Here is the html code

`` « left prev

```
 <button id="right">&raquo; right next</button>

 <div class="wrap">
 <div class="gallery">

 <div class="item">
 <img src="photos/1.jpg"  class="block" id="black">
 </div>


 <div class="item">
 <img src="photos/2.jpg"  class="block" id="black">
 </div>
 </div><!-- .gallery -->
  </div>  <!-- wrap -->
```

And here my JQUERY

```
$("#right").click(function(){
    if($(".block:last").offset().left <= 0 ) 
         {return;}
    else { 
        $(".block").animate({
            left: "-=110px"
        } , "slow" );
    }
});


$("#left").click(function(){
     if($(".block").offset().left >= 0 ) 
        {return;}
     else { 
        $(".block").animate({
            left: "+=110px"
        } , "slow" );
    }
 });
```

here is the demo but it doesnt run properly in jsfiddle but in browser it runs. http://jsfiddle.net/4bhL6p05/

Answer (score 0):

For jsfiddle, you need to add jQuery as a dependency (in the left hand column).

Regarding your question:

> I want to stop the last picture in the right side of the gallery, so it fills the gallery with last pictures because in my code it slides all last pictures and hides all.

You'll need to subtract the width of the `.gallery` element from your offset, so it does not animate off the screen. Something like this:

```
var g = $('.gallery').width();

$("#right").click(function(){
    if(($(".block:last").offset().left - g) <= 0 ) {
        ... logic
    }
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bhL6p05/10/

---

Edit: Here's a quick explanation! Honestly, the fiddle is not very different from your original. The only thing I did was calculate the "end" position. First, an image to help visualize:

[image: Explanation of what we're trying to do]

**The purple text under each black box is the `left` offset position.**

As you can see, when the elements are in the "starting" position, the first element has an offset of 0. The last image (in this example) has an offset of 400px (because each element is 100px).

Now, when the user clicks right, we subtract the offset. If we check against an offset of 0, our final image will be at the STARTING position (the far left). That's why, in your original code, the final image goes off screen (however, if you inspect the element, you'll see it only goes off screen and then stops animating - it doesn't keep animating.)

We want the last image to be at the right side, so we need to calculate the "ending" offset. We get that by grabbing the width of the container and subtracting the offset from that.

To improve the code (or, if you wanted to have the last image "flush" with the right (similar to how the first image starts)), you could calculate the difference between the final image, the elements width, and the distance to animate. Based on that, you could then vary the animation amount.

Hopefully this helps explain it a bit more.

Comment: Hey ! Thankyou for your code, it solved my problem with stopping the images when it reaches the end. but can you explain me the codes? because some of your code i dont understand. i am new to jquery.  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @jennydavis Added a photo, which hopefully explains it a bit more :)

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten your code a little bit so that it uses a variable 'current_pic' to keep track of your slide position instead of working with offset. I left a number of comments in the code to explain it.

JS/jQuery code:

```
<script>
    // it's always a good practice to wait until the document loads and then execute your js/jquery code
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // this variable keeps track of the current image displayed
        var current_pic = 0;
        // this variable is used to stop the slideshow at the last image
        var pic_count = $(".gallery > div").length;
        // my test images had a different width that your, so I used this variable to ensure that they get animated correctly
        // this works only if all the images have the same width
        var pic_width = $(".block").width();

        $("#right").click(function(){
            // if the expression was 'current_pic >= pic_count', the slideshow would slide past the last image and then stop
            // by decrementing 1 from the pic_count, you ensure that the slideshow stops at the last image
            if(current_pic >= pic_count-1) 
                {return;}
            else { 
                // the slideshow shifts one slide forward -> add 1 to current_pic
                current_pic++;
                $(".block").animate({
                    left: "-=" + pic_width
                } , "slow" );
            }
        });


        $("#left").click(function(){
            // this ensures that the slideshow doesn't shift past the first image
            if(current_pic <= 0) 
                {return;}
            else { 
                // the slideshow shifts one slide backwards -> decrement 1 from current_pic
                current_pic--;
                $(".block").animate({
                    left: "+=" + pic_width
                } , "slow" );
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

CSS code:

```
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0px;
    }
    #black {
        height: 90px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .block {
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

HTML code is the same as in your fiddle

Don't forget to include the jQuery library:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the code, but my images are not all the same, how was that ? and also, it runs but when you click next and it reaches the last image it doesnt stop.

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry to hear that the code is not working for you because it's working just fine for me.